# After reindexing magento 2 site through command line, site is not working

Tags: magento2, reindex

I did a reindex using below command through command line:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

After this command, my site home page is showing fine but when I click any link it is redirecting to http://error.webapps.net/error_4722.html this page and saying "This URL has been blocked. Error Code: 4722"

Here is my website url: https://atozdealsdirect.co.uk/

Please help me.

Comment: What kind of server are you on? This is a very strange issue.. Did you only try reindexing? Maybe try:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

and clear caches.

Comment: Issue got fixed after redoing the same commands. Thank you. Can you please try to look into this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043187/results-grid-is-not-visible-in-magento-e-commerce-site