# Results grid is not visible in Magento e commerce site

Tags: gridview, magento2

[Click this link to see an attached an image. **Result grid is not visible on few screens. Please can anyone suggest me a solution?** Magento Version 2.3.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2iJI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue with memory as page rendering doesn't look complete. Can you check the logs and see if you get any specific memory related warnings .

Comment: Grid is displaying results good in other few pages. Still I just checked logs and there is no error regarding memory issue.